# Offset and mouseevent pageX and Y are adding pixel

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Maybe the problem lies somewhere else but I am just not able to find the problem.

So I need a div to show when the customer clicks a link and it needs to show up at that spot.

I used .css({top: e.pageY, left: e.pageX}) but the divs were always out of screen. So then I tried offset and got the same Problem. Now when I move the position of the link to 0 0 and click it, the div is at top 1456.5px and left 262px. When I set top of the link to 200px, the div will be at top 1456.5px and left 62px.
I also tried subtracting the offset of the container. Still the same result. The difference is at 0 0 the div is at top 1055px and left 0px.
And at top 0 right 10px the div is at top 1045px and left 0px.

So still, for some reason top responds to right and left responds to top.

```js
$('.pulslink').on('click', function(e) {

  e.preventDefault();

  var title = this.title;
  var content = $(this).data('content');
  var offset = $(this).offset();

  $(this).find('.exit').show();

  $('.popover').css({
    top: offset.left,
    left: offset.top
  });
  $('.popover').show();

  $('.popover-header h3').text(title);
  $('.popover-body').text(content);
});
```

```css
.pulsar {
  background: blue;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin: 10px;
  height: 25px;
  width: 25px;
  animation: pulse 2s infinite;
  text-align: center;
}

.exit {
  color: white;
  font-size: 25px;
  display: none;
}

.pulslink {
  z-index: 100;
}

.test {
  position: absolute;
  top: 300px;
  right: 250px;
}

.test2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 250px;
  right: 900px;
}

.test3 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 450px;
  right: 600px;
}

.test4 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 450px;
  right: 1050px;
}

.test5 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 510px;
  right: 700px;
}

@keyframes pulse {
  0% {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(0, 17, 255, 0.7);
  }
  70% {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 10px rgba(0, 17, 255, 0);
  }
  100% {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(0, 17, 255, 0);
  }
}

.popover {
  height: 200px;
  width: 350px;
  background-color: white;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.popover-header {
  padding: 15px;
}

.popover-body {
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section>

  <div class='container'>

    <img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/img/couch-1835923_1920.jpg" class="img-info">

    <a href="" class="pulslink test" title="" data-content="">
      <div class="pulsar"><span class="exit">&times;</span></div>
    </a>
    <a href="" class="pulslink test2" title="" data-content="">
      <div class="pulsar"><span class="exit">&times;</span></div>
    </a>
    <a href="" class="pulslink test3" title="" data-content="">
      <div class="pulsar"><span class="exit">&times;</span></div>
    </a>
    <a href="" class="pulslink test4" title="" data-content='S'>
      <div class="pulsar"><span class="exit">&times;</span></div>
    </a>
    <a href="" class="pulslink test5" title="" data-content="">
      <div class="pulsar"><span class="exit">&times;</span></div>
    </a>

    <div class="popover">
      <div class="popover-header">
        <h3></h3>
      </div>
      <div class="popover-body"></div>
    </div>
  </div>





</section>
```

Answer (score 1):

All you need is, to use your mouse coordinates from the mouse click event: `e.pageX` is the horizontal position and `e.pageY` is the vertical position.

```js
$('.pulslink').on('click', function(e) {

  e.preventDefault();
  
  var title = this.title;
  var content = $(this).data('content');

  $(this).find('.exit').show();

  $('.popover').css({
    top: e.pageY + 'px',
    left: e.pageX + 'px'
  });
  $('.popover').show();

  $('.popover-header h3').text(title);
  $('.popover-body').text(content);
});
```

```css
.pulsar {
  background: blue;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin: 10px;
  height: 25px;
  width: 25px;
  animation: pulse 2s infinite;
  text-align: center;
}

.exit {
  color: white;
  font-size: 25px;
  display: none;
}

.pulslink {
  z-index: 100;
}

.test {
  position: absolute;
  top: 300px;
  right: 250px;
}

.test2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 250px;
  right: 900px;
}

.test3 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 450px;
  right: 600px;
}

.test4 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 450px;
  right: 1050px;
}

.test5 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 510px;
  right: 700px;
}

@keyframes pulse {
  0% {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(0, 17, 255, 0.7);
  }
  70% {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 10px rgba(0, 17, 255, 0);
  }
  100% {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(0, 17, 255, 0);
  }
}

.popover {
  height: 200px;
  width: 350px;
  background-color: white;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.popover-header {
  padding: 15px;
}

.popover-body {
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section>

  <div class='container'>

    <img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/img/couch-1835923_1920.jpg" class="img-info">

    <a href="" class="pulslink test" title="" data-content="">
      <div class="pulsar"><span class="exit">&times;</span></div>
    </a>
    <a href="" class="pulslink test2" title="" data-content="">
      <div class="pulsar"><span class="exit">&times;</span></div>
    </a>
    <a href="" class="pulslink test3" title="" data-content="">
      <div class="pulsar"><span class="exit">&times;</span></div>
    </a>
    <a href="" class="pulslink test4" title="" data-content='S'>
      <div class="pulsar"><span class="exit">&times;</span></div>
    </a>
    <a href="" class="pulslink test5" title="" data-content="">
      <div class="pulsar"><span class="exit">&times;</span></div>
    </a>

    <div class="popover">
      <div class="popover-header">
        <h3></h3>
      </div>
      <div class="popover-body"></div>
    </div>
  </div>

</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who might experience something similar, it actually works with offset pretty well, when you subtract the offset of the parent element.

I did make an mistake when calculating, switching left and top.

So a solution that did work for me is

```
 var left = offset.left - $('#info-container').offset().left;
        var top = offset.top - $('#info-container').offset().top;

        $(this).find('.exit').show();
    
        $('.popover').css({top: top, left: left});
```

I gave the container an ID so we wont get the offset of other containers.

Thank you everybody for your help